# NPP.EXEC and perl --> save output?

Tags: perl, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ under Windows 7. I used to use the npp.exec plugin for Perl applications, and it worked fine with the following code:

```
SET OUTFILE = C:\00_Data\output.txt
cmd /c 
c:\perl64\bin\perl.exe C:\00_Data\Scripts8\gra.pl dt "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" >$(OUTFILE) 
NPP_OPEN $(OUTFILE)
```

Since my update of Notepad++ to version 6.6.9 the Perl script starts, the results are written to the console (all is fine), but the defined output file is created and opened but empty, i.e., the results are not saved.

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Run Menu from Notepad++ to run a Perl file directly.

1. Go to Run
2. Type `C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe "$(FILE_NAME)"` or give path of perl exe file.
3. Press Save
4. Assign Shortcut.

The console closes pretty fast with this method, so add `[system("pause");]` to your Perl file  to show a "print any key to continue" message in console.